# Does resampling have to be instantiated in mlr3?

Tags: instantiation, mlr3

It was said that resampling object should be instantiated before training in mlr3 book. But sometimes it was not and can be trained and predicted successfully. I want to know when it should be instantiated with $instantiate(task) slot.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass an resampling object that is not instantiated, it will be instantiated internally by some/most methods.

In general, instantiate it.